# flutter container with different vertical spacings by the same contents

Tags: flutter-layout, dart-pub

I have different vertical spacing in two containers with the same contents. I have tried it with different widgets, it is always the same.
The 'Card' widget contains a 'Column' with two identical 'Containers', each containing an identical 'ListTile' with an identical 'child: Text'.
What can I do to make the vertical distances equal and as small as possible?

```
  Container(
width: screenWidth * 0.5, height: 300,
padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
child: Column(
   children: <Widget>[
     Container(
       width: screenWidth * 0.5, height: 280,
       padding: EdgeInsets.all(1),

       child: Card(
           shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
             borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8.0),),
             side: BorderSide(
               color: Colors.black,
               width: 1.0,),
           ),
           color: Colors.white,
           elevation: 4.0,
           shadowColor: Colors.blue,
           child: Column(
             mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,

             children:[
              Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                margin: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.yellow,
                  border: Border.all(color: Colors.black),
                ),
                   child: ListTile(
                     
                       contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 0.0, horizontal: 5.0),
                       dense: true,
                       isThreeLine: false,

                       title: Text(
                         selTitle,
                         style: TextStyle(
                           color:Colors.black,
                           //backgroundColor: Colors.limeAccent,
                           backgroundColor: selColor(selIndex),
                           fontSize: 20,
                           fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                         ),
                       )
                   )
                ),

                Container(
                   padding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                   margin: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                   decoration: BoxDecoration(
                     color: Colors.yellow,
                     border: Border.all(color: Colors.black),
                   ),
                   child: ListTile(
                     
                     contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 0.0, horizontal: 5.0),
                     dense: true,
                     isThreeLine: false,
                     title: Text(
                         "noch ein sehr langer Text: jihiuwh  uewua8h ieshg lisru hirluh spi",
                         style: TextStyle(
                           backgroundColor: myBTN_HELLGRAU,
                           fontSize: 16,
                         )
                     ),
                   )
              )

             ]

           )
       ),
     )
  ]
)
```

),

[see details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RHBMt.png) and
[here is the whole application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BhQfM.png)

The vertical distances in 'Andorra' are much larger than in the text below.
How do I get the spacing in the upper field smaller?

Comment: But I do not know why

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution. Insert into the first ListTile solved my problem:

```
visualDensity: VisualDensity(horizontal: 0, vertical: -4),
```